# JS Class with static method not seeing static setter

Tags: javascript, class, static, ecmascript-6

I have this simple code -

```
class Repo {
    constructor(someParam = null) {
        this.getDic = someParam;
    }
    static set getDic(ref){
        this.ref = ref;
    }
    static get getDic(){
        return this.ref;
    }
    static key(key){
        return this.getDic[key];
    }
}

let newRepo = new Repo({yeah: 'baby'});
Repo.key('yeah') // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'yeah' of undefined
```

Why is the 'getDic' getter undefined in the 'key' static method?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you believe `static` does?

Comment: @Bergi allows using the method/getter/setter without needing to instantiate the class... ?

Comment: Right. Then how do you expect the static method to access instance specific data?

Comment: @FelixKling You're absolutely right! Thank you! :)

Comment: Right. And that's the reason why static properties are accessed on `Repo`, not on `newRepo` (as you have now edited in). You most likely just don't want to use `static` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar problem; it turns out `this` doesn't refer to the static class the way you'd expect. Using the actual classname fixes it. So:

```
class Repo {
    . . .
    static key(key){
        return Repo.getDic[key];
    }
}
```

By swapping out the `this` for the classname, it should work properly.

Answer (score 4):

when you define a `static` property in the class its bind it to the `constructor` so when you do `new Repo()` the return value not containing the `static` method but `new Repo().constructor` will contain the `static` methods

```
let newRepo = new Repo({yeah: 'baby'});
Repo.key // defined
newRepo.key // not defined
newRepo.constructor.key // defined
```

and another thing: the `Repo.key === newRepo.constructor.key`. So by creating a `static` property (like in other language such as c#) the property lives once in the scope, but this is a completely different issue :)

**EDIT:**

The reason that your code isn't working is because you are using a `get` property as a `function`.

By putting the `set` key before a function property you are setting the function to be a `set` property... that means that the function is been set a `get` on `Object.definePropery`

Lets look at the convert `es6` using babel

```
'use strict';

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Repo = function () {
    function Repo() {
        var someParam = arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined ? null : arguments[0];

        _classCallCheck(this, Repo);

        this.getDic = someParam;
    }

    _createClass(Repo, null, [{
        key: 'key',
        value: function key(_key) {
            console.log(this.constructor.getDic);
            return this.getDic[_key];
        }
    }, {
        key: 'getDic',
        set: function set(ref) {
            this.ref = ref;
        },
        get: function get() {
            return this.ref;
        }
    }]);

    return Repo;
}();

var newRepo = new Repo({ yeah: 'baby' });
Repo.key('yeah'); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'yeah' of undefined
```

To make a long story shot just use `Repo.key = 'heya'` and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've edited my question to better reflect the problem. Do you have any input on that? Thanks!